# Download files using javascript and webservices

Tags: javascript, web-services, download

I need to download a list of files from an html page inside a public portal.
Files are in folders in an intranet server.

From the html page, using javascript I call an asp.net webservice that reads a file, and sends its content as a byte array.

How can I download/show that file using that byte array from the javascript function?

Thanks,
Fabio

Answer (score 4):

It isn't going to work exactly as you describe it. You can't save a byte array to a file from javascript.

What you can do is to link to a "service" that returns the file as its response with the proper headers to cause the browser to open a save dialog.